# Opencart: add module/html inside .TPL

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Is there a simple way of calling a module (in this case *module/html*) inside a div of the TPL, in WordPress we could use shortcodes to do that, is there any way to do something like that in OpenCart without having to create a new layout position using only the module id for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open controller file of your tpl. For example in *catalog/controller/common/header.php*

Find (should be row 3)

```
public function index($setting) {
```

Add after

```
$this->load->model('extension/module');
$module_id = 5;  // your html module ID
$custom_html = $this->model_extension_module->getModule($module_id);

if ($custom_html && $custom_html['status']) {
  $data['module_html'] = $this->load->controller('extension/module/html', $custom_html);
}else{
  $data['module_html'] = '';
}
```

Than in *header.tpl* add

```
<?php echo $module_html; ?>
```